# CMake : C and CXX compiler identification is unknown Win10 CMakeGUI

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, cmake, cmake-gui

So I am trying to configure a file based on this tutorial on youtube which is very simple :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYmgbqGfv-8

I use CMake GUI in Windows 10 and I have a running Visual Studio 2015 which is able to build c++ projects already (I've used it for some time)

I use "Visual Studio 15 2017"

I created a folder named hellocmake and hellocmake/build for both inputs:

[my inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPdT7.png)

However when I tried to configure, it says that

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (PROJECT):
>
> *No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.*
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (PROJECT):
>
> *No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.*

The error log specifies that it can't find the two compiler files :
    Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
    Compiler:
    Build flags: 
    Id flags:

```
The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified
```

I tried downloading the "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" and "CMakeCXXCompilerId.c" files and try to add them manually in the same folder, but it doesnt solve it

I tried to look up several other sources which have a similar case but I can't seem to understand them.
This problem didn't exist with my old computer so I assume it has something to do with the Visual Studio ?

Thank you guys, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 13):

You selected Visual Studio 2017 which you don't have installed. I think you confused the actual version number (which is 15 for VS2017) for the year in which the version was released. Pick a VS2015 generator (version number 14) and it should work.

Comment: @Aldoaldo please mark this answer. Always when someone resolves your problem mark the answer as solution.rubenvv: thanks! You helped me too!

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @rubenvb's answer, add a tip: before you execute change "15" to "14", you should remove the "CMakeCache.txt" file.

```
cmake -G
```

[image]

Comment: If that's an addition to an existing answer - better put is as a comment rather than as a separate answer

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have 50 reputation, so can't  comment on other's answer