# Cannot build LLVM on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm, cmake-gui

I'm trying to install LLVM on Windows 10 using Visual Studio, using the guide http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html, but I'm getting errors:

Here is my view in CMake GUI, where I've directed it to use the C++ compiler `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe`.

I've already created a new directory called llvm for the build, since I cannot build in the source directory.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

The configure process displays the following output:

```
The C compiler identification is unknown
The CXX compiler identification is unknown
The ASM compiler identification is MSVC
Found assembler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:48 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "MSBuild.exe" "cmTC_c88f4.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0"
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:44 (message):
  The C++ compiler "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
  14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: C:/dev/llvm/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"MSBuild.exe" "cmTC_c88f4.vcxproj"
  "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0"



  Generator: execution of make failed.  Make command was: "MSBuild.exe"
  "cmTC_c88f4.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0"





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:48 (project)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/dev/llvm/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/dev/llvm/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: On a correct installation CMake will find its way to the MSVC compiler paths just fine. Doublecheck ACLs and privileges and/or repair your installation.

Comment: Could it be because I've MinGW installed? Also, what are ACL's?

Comment: [ACLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list).. slightly misused term to say: check files and folders permissions.

Comment: I start Cmake as admin :(

Comment: Above the output area: `Current Generator: Visual Studio 15 2017`. This generator is not suitable for your Visual Studio 14. [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40975780/cmake-c-and-cxx-compiler-identification-is-unknown-win10-cmakegui) has been asked yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with your same setup(exception being Windows 32-bit), the LLVM version I have chosen is 4.0.0. I followed the tutorial for setting it up with clang.

I made notes for my entire process. 
Instructions for building LLVM 4.0.0 from source:

- Create a folder named LLVM in any suitable location.
- cd LLVM
- svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk llvm
- cd llvm\tools
- svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk clang
- cd ....   # going back to where you started
- mkdir build
- cd build
- cmake -G "Visual Studio 14" ..\llvm    ##depends on the version of VS you use, I used VS 2015 -> VISUAL STUDIO 14.0
- If successful, in the build directory you will find LLVM.sln file which can be opened in Visual Studio, once opened, you can navigate through the solution explorer and right click the ALL_BUILD project -> Build.

Notes:

- I'm using Visual Studio 2015 (Update 3)
- I'm using Windows 10 32-bit system
- Header files dependencies can be fixed by appending paths to the files where it can be found in the Visual Studio 14.0 folder in Program Files.
- My environment variables for reference:

  **INCLUDE=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt;

  **LIBPATH=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral;\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0\References\CommonConfiguration\neutral;
- Set the PATH enviroment variable for llvm tools like clang, llc, lli, etc., if they're not recognized on developer command prompt.
- You may also find executables like clang and clang++ missing from the build when downloading from the github. I copied these from the prebuilt binaries which I had downloaded for windows which can be found on the LLVM releases page.

Hope this helps!